# Compare a numpy array to each element of another one

Tags: python, numpy, comparison

```
A = np.array([5,1,5,8])
B = np.array([2,5])
```

I want to compare the A array to each element of B. In other words I'm lookin for a function which do the following computations :

```
A>2
A>5
(array([ True, False,  True,  True]), array([False, False, False,  True]))
```

Comment: `[A > b for b in B]`?

Comment: Yes lol. I was looking for something more numpyic but that's fine also.

Comment: You can use broadcasting `A>B[:,None]`

Comment: Wonderful@Brenlla, thks. Could you esplain why does it work?

Comment: By adding a an extra dimension to `B`, it sort off "expands" the last dimension of `B` to match the dimension of `A`. I know it doesn't make a lot of sense, but it is posibly the most important feature of numpy. For more details see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules)

Comment: Thk you, Sir Brenlla.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not particularly fancy but a list comprehension will work:

```
[A > b for b in B]

[array([ True, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool),
 array([False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)]
```

You can also use [`np.greater()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.greater.html), which requires the dimension-adding trick that Brenlla uses in the comments:

```
np.greater(A, B[:,np.newaxis])

array([[ True, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Yeah, right but I prefer the Brenlla version ... A>B[:,None] as it give me a numpy array

Comment: Sure, I like that one too!  (But you can always just wrap this answer in `np.array()`.)

Comment: @hans glick there *is* an explicit Numpy function for pairwise comparison of two vectors, see updated answer.

Comment: I'm confused, is the greater function what you are referring to with your last comment, because that still uses explicit broadcasting. Is there any built in numpy function which produces an n*m output of comparisons without explicit broadcasting (even if such a function just performs broadcasting behind the scenes). I'm fine with doing the broadcasting myself, but if a method exists that wraps it, I'd rather use that for readability