# compare numpy arrays of different lengths entry by entry

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking to compare each entry of one numpy array of dimensions (100, 1) to each entry of another numpy array of dimensions (59, 1) without using any loops. Is there a way to do that?

More specifically, say I have these two arrays:

```
a = np.random.randn(100,1)
b = np.random.randn(59,1)
```

for each element in b, I want to count the number of elements in a that are greater than that element in b.

Comment: Sorry, this question has already been answered:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51822589/compare-a-numpy-array-to-each-element-of-another-one

Comment: `(b<a.T).sum(axis=1)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare a numpy array to each element of another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51822589/compare-a-numpy-array-to-each-element-of-another-one)